# script if variable empty not execute command, if variable available execute

Tags: bash, shell, puppet

I am writing a script to disable the puppet agent. I would like to implement this logic:

- if `reason` variable null or empty, halt with an explanatory message;
- else execute the disabling command (`puppet agent --disable "$reason"`)

How can I write the `if` condition in the `execute()` function in the below script to achieve that?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

lockfile='/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/agent_disabled.lock'
reason='who'

execute () {
    if [[ -z $reason && ${reason+x} ]]; then
      echo "Disabling reason is not set"
    fi
}

puppet agent --disable "$reason"


# Verify if the Agent is Disabled or not
if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
  echo 'puppet agent is disabled'
fi
```

Comment: Use `:+` instead of `+`, maybe…? `man bash` has a detailed description of the differences in its *Expansions* section.

Comment: I've updated the question prose to reflect my understanding of the question in more idiomatic English, but I hesitate to answer the question because it seems more than a little off: the script does not presently call the `execute` function, so its contents do not have any effect on whether the `puppet agent --disable` command is executed.

Comment: Also, the `-z $reason` condition should be sufficient by itself to determine whether `$reason` is is empty or null (or unset) *vs* defined with a non-null value, so it's unclear what purpose the `${reason+x}` part is intended to serve.

Comment: In your script, you define a function named _execute_, but never call it ... it is dead code. Note also that the "verification" part of your code won't be executed, if `puppet` returns a non-zero exit code. I can't say whether this is or is not what you want to have.

Comment: Please don't make edits that invalidate the answers already given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my clarifying edit to the question to have adequately captured the intent, we have

> - if reason variable null or empty, halt with an explanatory message;

Bash's `-z` conditional operator can catch both null and empty cases, including when the value is null on account of the variable not being set at all, but remember that it is evaluated *after* the command is fully expanded.  Possibly, then, this is the test you want to perform:

```
if [[ -z "$reason" ]]; then # ...
```

> - else execute the disabling command (`puppet agent --disable "$reason"`)

Your example code executes that command unconditionally.  I guess you instead want to put it in an `else` block of the condition, or otherwise perform it only in the event that the previous condition is not satisfied.

I don't really see any gain from using a function here.  I would probably implement what I think you are describing like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

lockfile='/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/agent_disabled.lock'
reason='who:until:why'

if [[ -z "$reason" ]]; then
  echo "Disabling reason is not set"  1>&2
else
  puppet agent --disable "$reason"

  # Verify that the agent is disabled
  if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
    echo 'puppet agent is disabled'  1>&2
  fi
fi
```

Alternatively, I don't see how the disablement reason could ever fail to meet the criterion in the code presented, so maybe you mean to write a wrapper function that takes the reason as an argument:

```
disable_puppet() {
  local reason=$1

  if [[ -z "$reason" ]]; then
    echo "Disabling reason is not set" 1>&2
  else
    puppet agent --disable "$reason"

    # Verify that the agent is disabled
    if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
      echo 'puppet agent is disabled' 1>&2
    fi
  fi
}
```

Comment: first example what i am looking for. thank you very much.
one more question, other way around, how i can adopt in the script, so user can enter input reason while executing script not adding variable in the script. could you please give me example from your first code.

Comment: One question per question, @Sha.  However, the `read` command is one of the easier ways to read from the standard input.  Perhaps that is what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean the we are are setting reason in variable, i mean i am looking other way as well like reason not set in var but while executing script, user should provide input for reason. i mean interactive while executing script.

Comment: I already told you, @Sha: the script can read interactive input (into a variable) via Bash's `read` built-in.  If you want another full answer then pose another full question, but do perform your due diligence first.  I'm sure there already Q&As here at SO that address this.